# How to separate unit and integration tests when in gradle project with micronaut and kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, micronaut, kapt

I'm attempting separate unit and integration tests into separate Gradle tasks in Gradle project with Micronaut and Kotlin, using Gradle's Kotlin DSL for Gradle build file.

I followed the usual steps from Gradle's documentation, but it seems I'm missing some Micronaut specific setup steps, particularly related to kapt.

Here's my `build.gradle.kts` that I've adapted from the standard Micronaut project template:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.5.21"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "2.0.8"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.5.21"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example"

val kotlinVersion=project.properties.get("kotlinVersion")
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
    }
}

sourceSets {
    create("intTest") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
    }
}

val intTestImplementation: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
}

configurations["intTestRuntimeOnly"].extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())


dependencies {
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    kapt("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    kapt("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc")
    implementation("io.micronaut.flyway:micronaut-flyway")
    implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-pubsub")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-extension-functions")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")

    //Testing dependencies
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4")
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:3.2.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")

    //Integration testing dependencies
    intTestImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    intTestImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
    intTestImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers")
    intTestImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")
 
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}


val integrationTest = task<Test>("intTest") {
    description = "Runs integration tests."
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["intTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["intTest"].runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}

tasks.check { dependsOn(integrationTest) }

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```

If now I run my integration test that looks like this:

```
@MicronautTest
internal class ExampleIntegrationTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {}
}
```

I get the error:

```
org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition [io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension]: @MicronautTest used on test but no bean definition for the test present. This error indicates a misconfigured build or IDE. Please add the 'micronaut-inject-java' annotation processor to your test processor path (for Java this is the testAnnotationProcessor scope, for Kotlin kaptTest and for Groovy testCompile). See the documentation for reference: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluationException(ConditionEvaluator.java:81)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluate(ConditionEvaluator.java:69)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.lambda$evaluate$0(ConditionEvaluator.java:55)
    at java.base@15.0.2/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
...
```

Which leads be to believe that there's something Micronaut or Kapt related missing in my conifg. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The issue I was experiencing happened because kapt was not configured to work with newly added integration test source set. Kotlin's annotation processing for micronaut is configured in `microunaut` plugin configuration's `processing` block. What I needed to do was to add additional source set there:

```
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
        additionalSourceSets.add(sourceSets.getByName("intTest")) //add additional integration testing sources set
    }
}
```

For this to work `sourceSet` section needed to come before `microunaut` plugin config section.

Final result, where everything worked as expected looked like this:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.5.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.5.21"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "2.0.8"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.5.21"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example"

val kotlinVersion=project.properties.get("kotlinVersion")
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Include integration test source sets and configurations
sourceSets {
    create("intTest") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
    }
}
val intTestImplementation: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
}
val intTestRuntimeOnly: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testRuntimeOnly.get())
}

// Micronaut plugin to set runtime, test platform, and annotation processing
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
        additionalSourceSets.add(sourceSets.getByName("intTest"))
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    kapt("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    kapt("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc")
    implementation("io.micronaut.flyway:micronaut-flyway")
    implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-pubsub")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-extension-functions")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")

    //Testing dependencies
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4")
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:3.2.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")

    //Integration testing dependencies
    intTestImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    intTestImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
    intTestImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers")

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}


// Integration test gradle task
val integrationTest = task<Test>("intTest") {
    description = "Runs integration tests."
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["intTest"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["intTest"].runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}

tasks.check { dependsOn(integrationTest) }

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was banging my head against this error for a while. Do you know why the additionalSourceSets line is required for Kotlin but not Java?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gradle plugin 'jvm-test-suite'. So I have this in my build.gradle file:

```
testing {
suites {
    integration(JvmTestSuite) {
        dependencies {
            implementation project()
        }
        configurations {
            integrationCompileClasspath.extendsFrom testCompileClassPath
            integrationRuntimeClasspath.extendsFrom testRuntimeClasspath
            integrationImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
            integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
        }
    }
}
}
check.dependsOn { testing.suites.integration }
```

And in the /src folder I created a folder/package integration with 3 sub-packages - groovy, java, resources, as I use Spock for testing. So now I have

```
com.example/
├── src/
└── integration/
└── main/
└── test/
```